# Which font is used in the Monero logo?

Tags: monero-community

This is a relevant question for developers. Which font is used in the Monero logo, found [here](https://downloads.getmonero.org/resources/branding.zip)?

Comment: It's probably a custom font - or at least a modified font.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but if you dive into the files of the official [branding package](https://downloads.getmonero.org/resources/branding.zip), you'll be able to see in the `Monero-Logo.ai` file the following: `%%For: (Riccardo Spagni) ()`. Maybe he knows who knows …

Answer (score 4):

Riccardo Spagni (fluffypony) stated that the logo uses Century Gothic [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3g68b2/i_too_created_a_couple_of_monero_accepted_here/ctw49h4/).

The 'R' used in some versions (current branding package) doesn't seem to belong in the font family though. The 'E' also looks slighty wider. It's likely customized from the [original submission](https://99designs.com/logo-design/contests/monero-mro-cryptocurrency-logo-design-contest-382486).

Comment: It's Century Gothic, some letters are slightly modified for kerning and typography as you've noted. These modifications were made by the original GUI designer:)

Answer (score 0):

Monero uses a modified version of Century Gothic.

You can see the differences here and download a free Monero version.

https://www.monerooutreach.org/monero-typography.php